# UV Maps for stencils?

Tags: uv

i hope what im trying to do is simple but im still learning how to use Blender fully. I modeled a helmet in blender recently and found out how to unfold it via UV mapping. My question is, how can I do this but keep the dimensions i made for my model? How would i print it out to scale? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let me use a hypothetical to see if I have this right... Imagine you have gone to properties and set Blenders units to `cm`, You have made a cube that is 3x3x3, You UV unwrap this cube, leaving a UV map comprised of 6 joined squares. You want to be able to print an image of this UV map and have the resulting image (6 joined squares) comprised of 3cm x 3cm squares in real-world units (like you could measure with a ruler)?

Comment: bingo! you explained this better than I haha. Yes, I wanted to make my 3d object into a flat version of itself but keep the measurements of the 3d object i built to scale so that i can use it for cosplay purposes. I did it once awhile back and i think the UV map turned out a little larger than i had wanted it to. I was wondering if this is something easy to do or is it set to act that way to begin with?

Comment: Well, glad I interpreted it correctly , unfortunately, I have no idea how to do that. I'll look into it and see what I can find. In the meantime, I'll up-vote this question in the hopes someone who does know how to do this comes alone.

Comment: thank you! I have been combing google trying to find the answer but it seems to only come up with stuff having to do with not stretching textures out..

Comment: You may find the **Papaer Model** addon, (comes already bundled in Blender so just need to enable it) interesting. I have never tried it but from watching the video seems once you have your seams correctly marked you would be ready to go. Select the page size you will be printing and the scale to 1 then export and check out the results. I notice it also has a Create UV option aswell which may be usefull for editing the UV islands rotation and position etc . /www.youtube.com/watch?v=klran7MH5Yw

Comment: Another approach which uses Blender in the workflow **From 3D Model to Foam Pattern | Cosplay Tutorial**  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wRBk9npIevQ  Search with : Blender cosplay creation produces all these  : https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+cosplay+creation

Comment: Ooooo I may try that when I get home today! This is the first I'm hearing of this addon!!

Comment: AH Kamui yes haha i've seen this video... i was just thinking instead of having to do a paper model, cut it out,and complete it just to tear it back down again to make smaller stencils for foam cutting, i was thinking if i had a simple mask unlike this one in the video,  if i could make a large stencil that i know would curve correctly via foam but come out in one large piece i.e. (half the mask) then, i would have less seams etc. Figured i would ask to see if someone knew something about how to do this.